# Dice function variables holds only max two increments

Tags: php, dice

I want to make an php site that throws a dice and then count up how many times you get each of it.

But the variables in the php doesnt increment properly, what do I do wrong here?

This is what I have at the moment:

```
<form action="" method="get">
                <input type="submit" value="Kast en terning" name="kastTerning"/>
            </form>

            <?php
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["terning1"] = 0;
            $_SESSION["terning2"] = 0;
            $_SESSION["terning3"] = 0;
            $_SESSION["terning4"] = 0;
            $_SESSION["terning5"] = 0;
            $_SESSION["terning6"] = 0;

            function oppgave5() {
                if (isset($_GET["kastTerning"])) {
                    $roll = rand(1, 6);
                    if ($roll == 1) {
                        $_SESSION["terning1"] ++;
                    } elseif ($roll == 2) {
                        $_SESSION["terning2"] ++;
                    } elseif ($roll == 3) {
                        $_SESSION["terning3"] ++;
                    } elseif ($roll == 4) {
                        $_SESSION["terning4"] ++;
                    } elseif ($roll == 5) {
                        $_SESSION["terning5"] ++;
                    } elseif ($roll == 6) {
                        $_SESSION["terning6"] ++;
                    }

                }
                return $roll;

            }


                oppgave5();
                echo "Du kastet " .oppgave5() ."</br>";
                echo "1 kom " . $_SESSION["terning1"] . " ganger.</br>";
                echo "2 kom " . $_SESSION["terning2"] . " ganger.</br>";
                echo "3 kom " . $_SESSION["terning3"] . " ganger.</br>";
                echo "4 kom " . $_SESSION["terning4"] . " ganger.</br>";
                echo "5 kom " . $_SESSION["terning5"] . " ganger.</br>";
                echo "6 kom " . $_SESSION["terning6"] . " ganger.</br>";
                ?>
```

Comment: you're resetting all your dice everytime, you know?

Comment: @Frederico, I had a hunch. Also different approach has been tried out, nothing works! I'm really stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$_SESSION["terning1"] = 0;
$_SESSION["terning2"] = 0;
$_SESSION["terning3"] = 0;
$_SESSION["terning4"] = 0;
$_SESSION["terning5"] = 0;
$_SESSION["terning6"] = 0;
```

to

```
// set them to 0 only when you start a new session.
if (!isset($_SESSION["terning1"], $_SESSION["terning2"], $_SESSION["terning3"], $_SESSION["terning4"], $_SESSION["terning5"], $_SESSION["terning6"])) {
    $_SESSION["terning1"] = $_SESSION["terning2"] = $_SESSION["terning3"] = $_SESSION["terning4"] = $_SESSION["terning5"] = $_SESSION["terning6"] = 0;
}
```

otherwise every time you reload the page you set them to `0`.